# Append custom menu items to a fixed menu

Tags: menu

Our product has a fixed set of menu items. I would like my users to be able to add items to the (main) menu, but I do not want them to change our fixed menu.

eg. **fixed menu**
Home   MyCoMenu1  MyCoMenu2

**End user can add their own items but not alter fixed menu items**
Home   MyCoMenu1  MyCoMenu2  Custom1  Custom2

I have already restricted menu-access in the end-user in the backend of Joomla. But the best I can do is not allow the end-user to delete a menu item, but he can unpublish it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please consider introducing yourself by editing your profile.  Do we need to know about the complexity of this task?  Are submenu items a possibility in `MyCoMenu1`?  Are you expecting the menu items to maintain a depth of 1 (no submenus)?  I'm not sure if this is necessary for resolving the task, just considering the scope of your question.

Comment: All menu items will have submenu items: both the company fixed menu and the custom menu.